# Select all distinct large data ElasticSearch in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have more than 10 million documents for each index in ElasticSeach, stored:

```
{
    "_index": "p0469ca75f014b098903dfab93f82bdf",
    "_type": "2017-11-19",
    "_id": "AV_hfU1dXj-tw7Td5MWR",
    "_score": 5.099111,
    "_source": {
      "date": "2017-11-19",
      "query": "this is keywords"
    }
}
```

After the distinct query using Terms Aggregations, more than 100 thousand lines remain.

How can I get the whole 100 thousand lines as fast as possible using PHP?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: I used Aggs terms to query, but the problem was that the data was so large that Elasticsearch returned very slowly